# Performing correlation analysis on a variable with separate count columns

Tags: correlation, spss

I'm looking at a variable that has two options: "Presence of Condition" has two headings "Yes" and "No" with large numbers of both. I'm trying to figure out how to consolidate both so that I can have one variable "Presence of Condition" and use that data to correlate with other variable. I'd have to separate the correlation process so it's done with variables "CONDITION_YES" and "CONDITION_NO" which I'd rather not.

I'm thinking of making one of the options negative, so that the numbers of people without the condition are counted as negative numbers.

My problem is checking the correlation of condition with other elements. I want the correlation to come up as *one* variable without having to type each of the entries individually.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this one variable quite easily - call it, e.g. "disease" and give it a value of 1 if disease is present and 0 if disease is absent.

You can then correlate this with other variables using point-biserial correlations.

Comment: The data is too large to do that. The counts have been presented as numbers like 5000 --- 2000 etc. Wouldn't be able to type each one in.

Comment: You can do it automatically in any statistical program or even in Excel. What format is your data in now? (Please edit your question to show a sample of your data).